# Kubuntu - Can't read picture from ExFat SD card, but can read it from Windows or when copied on external NTFS drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, sd-card, exfat

I formatted my 64 GB SD card for my camera directly via the camera software. It formatted it in ExFat, and I have been able to view or copy pictures taken with the camera easily on Windows.

But when I try to view them from the SD card on Kubuntu, nothing works. Using the CLI with Feh, I get a 'No Imlib2 loader for that file format'. Using Gwenview, I get a 'Loading meta information failed'. With Firefox, 'The image file:///XXX.JPG cannot be displayed because it contains errors.'. And sometimes the DCIM folder "crashes" and when I 'ls' inside I get an input / output error. All these errors are pointing to a problem with the metadata of the pictures.

But if I copy these pictures on an external drive (in NTFS) on a Windows system, then read them on my Kubuntu system, it works as intended. No Imlib2 error, no broken metadata it seems.

I tried reinstalling exfat-fuse / exfat-utils, but I got nothing.

I tried using a 2GB SD card formatted in Fat16, and it worked as intended.

Also, other files are accessible, both those written by me or the camera.

I'm running on Ubuntu 19.04 and Linux 5.0.0-25-generic.

What can I do to make it work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK on 16.04 there is a problem with 64+GB SD cards (this is a Linux bug, kernel and/or filesystem module). If yoiu want a better diagnostic, add your Kubuntu release and kernel version to your question.

Comment: @xenoid Oh yeah, sorry, I'm running on Ubuntu 19.04 and Linux 5.0.0-25-generic. And my SD card is 64GB, so maybe we're onto something. I should try formatting it in Fat or something like this, see if the camera can write to it and if my computer can see the pictures. Thanks!

Comment: I also tried another SD card of 2GB, in Fat16, and it worked. But I can't use it in ExFat with the camera, or the 64GB in Fat16 / 32 so I can't see if it's due to the size or the format.